# Tossing a fair coin with intention to quit once ahead

Tags: probability, probability-theory, gambling

If a person were to bet on a fair coin toss and on each toss placed a dollar bet on heads with the strategy to quit once ahead by a dollar or after 20 tosses (whichever comes sooner). Assume an infinite bank roll. What is the probability of this person winning $1?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** This is the same as the probability that the first passage time of a simple random walk to $S_n =1$ is less than or equal to $20.$ The first passage time $\tau(1)$ has distribution $$P(\tau(1) = 2m-1) = \frac{P(S_{2m-1}=1)}{2m-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Found this which answers similar question.

http://personal.vu.nl/h.c.tijms/APMNarticle.pdf